# Change marker position - ui-gmap-google-map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I have problem with marker in ui-gmap-google-map. I want change position my marker but when I selected other city my marker doesn't wants change position. 
Can anybody help?

Contoller

```
  setListeners = () ->   
    $scope.$watch('selectedField.id', (val) ->
      if val    
        $scope.marker = {
          id: 0,
          coords: {
            latitude: val.marker.latitude
            longitude: val.marker.longitude
          },
        }
    , true)
```

View

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedField.id" theme="select2">
  <ui-select-match>
    <span ng-bind="$select.selected.street"></span>
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (fieldsList  | filter: $select.search)">
     <span ng-bind="item.street"></span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

...

<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
  <ui-gmap-marker
    idKey='marker.id'
    coords='marker.coords'
    options='marker.options'
    >
  </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/tF899/13/

Comment: not exactly. I have marker's coords in object, and i want change position marker by code. Not by drag and drop ;)